# Calling a function in CKEditor from a SWF file in a plugin dialog

Tags: ckeditor

How would I go about calling a function in CKEditor from a SWF file in a plugin dialog that closes the dialog after adding an image to the editor?

Comment: Inside the SWF I have worked out to do something like:

ExternalInterface.call("CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction('??')");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var functionNumber = CKEDITOR.tools.addFunction(function(url){
            this.insertHtml('<img src="'+url+'" />');
            CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent().click('cancel');
        }, editor);
```

then send that functionNumber to the SWF to send back with callFunction